# PHP simple html dom return json

Tags: php, json, curl, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to handle with php scraping using cURL and Simple Html Dom Parser, but i'm getting stuck while return json format. Website is a free webscraper test website..

```
function getPage($href) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    $html = str_get_html($str);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $html;
}

$link = 'https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers';
$data = getPage($link);

foreach ($data->find('div[class=col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4]') as $key => $finder) {

    $img = $finder->find('img[class=img-responsive]');
    $imgCrt = $img->src;
    $price = $finder->find('h4[class=pull-right price]');
    $priceCrt = $price->innertext;
    $desc = $finder->find('p[class=description]');
    $descCrt = $desc->innertext;

    $json['status'] = 'ok';

    $json['return'][] = [
      'img' => $imgCrt,
      'price' => $priceCrt,
      'desc' => $descCrt
    ];
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

**Result:**

```
{"status":"ok","return":[{"img":null,"price":null,"desc":null},{"img":null,"price":null,"desc":null},{"img":null,"price":null,"desc":null}]}
```

And errors...

[image: https://i.imgur.com/7scD2Yg.png]

Line 43, 45, 47:

```
43 - $imgCrt = $img->src;
45 - $priceCrt = $price->innertext;
47 - $descCrt = $desc->innertext;
```

Whitout those lines my result page become blank, with no erros and no json results..
Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION!!**

While dumping discovered this:

```
var_dump($finder->find('img')[0]->src);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($finder->find('h4.price')[0]->innertext);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($finder->find('p.description')[0]->innertext);
```

Now works like a cham in:

```
$img[$key] = $finder->find('img')[0]->src;
$price[$key] = $finder->find('h4.price')[0]->innertext;
$desc[$key] = $finder->find('p.description')[0]->innertext;

$json['return'][] = [
  'img' => $img[$key],
  'price' => $price[$key],
  'desc' => $desc[$key]
];
```

Result:
img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHGAL.png

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Seems like `$finder->find()` isn't returning an object, this means it could be empty, an array, a string, etc etc

Comment: See what each scalar or vector is in your PHP like this: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($img->src, TRUE).'</pre>';` etc... It should tell you the type of value it is (array, stdClass object etc...)

Comment: @ShaunBebbers Or just `...print_r($img, true)...`, it may give a better idea of what it actually contains as well

Comment: If you have an `array` for our `$img` variable, use `$img['src']` for instance, depending on the debug of its contents

Answer (score 0):

Is  `$imgCrt = $img->src;` an object or array?

try `$imgCrt = $img['src'];`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 7, once you have confirmed what type of scalar or vector your variable is, you could do something like this:

```
$imgCrt = $img['src'] ?? $img->src;
```

Translated, this is:

```
$imgCrt = is_array($img) && !empty($img['src']) ? $img['src'] : $img->src;
```

This assumes that your key is `src` in your `$img` variable.

Please see my comments for how to debug and see what values and value types.

Also remember to set a HTTP response code -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Answer (score 0):

Your aren't finding any elements in your `->find` call, that is why you're getting those errors.
The Simple html parser uses CSS selectors in the find method, the attribute you're searching for has spaces in it therefore it must be quoted.
Also `find` returns an array unless you specify an index

```
foreach ($data->find('div["class=col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4"]') as $key => $finder) {

    $img = $finder->find('img[class=img-responsive]', 0);
    $imgCrt = $img->src;
    $price = $finder->find('h4[class="pull-right price"]', 0);
    $priceCrt = $price->innertext;
    $desc = $finder->find('p[class=description]', 0);
    $descCrt = $desc->innertext;

    $json['status'] = 'ok';

    $json['return'][] = [
      'img' => $imgCrt,
      'price' => $priceCrt,
      'desc' => $descCrt
    ];
}
```